Is this a bed bug shell?
What is this bug shell I found under the bed at our rental home on the Oregon coast in the US? The head was about the size of a pencil eraser and the body was larger.
Thank you!
-Laura

I have additional photos, but I'm not sure how to post them...

I found another shell that was a bit more recent and definitely a "potato" or "pill" bug. The little projections at the head were similar. Does this photo fit that type of insect?

Confirmed by an entomologist: it's a sow bug (AKA pill bug or potato bug). They like high humidity areas...

In that case you can self-answer. Just write an answer using the box below. I would include the details from the entomologist that confirmed that this is a sow bug rather than anything else, just to make sure that it makes a quality answer. - Don't just write "It is a sow bug, confirmed by an entomolgist" - add some detail.

Entomologist-identification: Sow bug

Welcome. answers to species ID require a link with background information, a photo of the identified species confirming the image in the question and, preferably, your post needs additional detail that supports the ID, such as overlapping natural habitats etc.
